# rails production environment concurrent read/write cache data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, concurrency

I have a rails3 application,use apache/passenger in production environment.
I have CarryingBill model,it has a bill_no attribute,the bill_no is auto generate before create,I use Rails cache (FileStore) to cache the current bill_no,when create a new CarryingBill Model, use Rails.cache.read('bill_no') to get the current bill_no value, then
set the CarryingBill instance bill_no, and call Rails.cache.write('bill_no',current_bill_no + 1) ,and so on.
But when multi user concurrent create the CarryingBill model,the generated bill_no is duplicated,how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One clever way is to create a BillNo model and coorresponding table with just an id attribute. Each time you create a CarryingBill, create a new BillNo record and assign it's id to the CarryingBill. That way you're using your db's auto-generated id for that model as your unique id maker..

```
class CarryingBill
   before_create :make_bill_no
   def make_bill_no
       bill = BillNo.create
       self.bill_no = bill.id
   end
 end
```

Comment: may be it is clever way code,but if i have 1000000 carrying bill record, also i have 1000000 bill_no model record,when i load a carrying model ,is it slowly?

Comment: Since it's just numbers, you probably wouldn't get a hit in performance, but check this out.. You can call bill.destroy after self.bill_no = bill.id and it would take care of that concern. ;)

Comment: the question is : is cache FileStore support safe concurrent request,because the CarryingBill mode have another attr called goods_no,the goods_no value is calcualte before create,the value logic is :goods_no = attr1 + attr2 + (the count where model attr1 = attr1_value and attr2 = attr2_value and bill_date = Date.today),how to reslove the problem?